# cookie_name on webapp2_extras session and auth

Tags: google-app-engine, session, authentication

I'm working in a Google App Engine project using python.
I'm using webapp2_extras modules **sessions** and **auth** together in a project and I have just find out that those two models put different cookies on the browser.

1. sessions module use by default cookie name "session" and stores the session for each connection
2. auth module use by default cookie name "auth" and stores the auth cookie once you login.

My question is:

Can this modules be set to use the same cookie name on the config? Is that correct? Or need to be apart?

If I set them to use the same cookie name, then they will overwrite the same cookie or just set it once?

Thanks!

Comment: why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: These are two different modules storing different data in different cookies. Why would you want them to overwrite each other? This would only cause breakage...

Comment: I just want to understand. They are two different modules but they auth use sessions. I don't know why do I need two cookies one for session and one for an authenticated user. I mean, the cookie for the authenticated user is a session too.